# How can I use grep to search for lines that start with a certain character in bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep, alias

I want an alias ('ggg') that will look through my existing set of aliases and tell me all the ones that *begin with* g.  I have a lot of g* aliases :)

I tried this: `alias ggg='alias | grep ^g'` but didn't give me any output (or error).  The thing I'm most unsure about is the 'start of line' character.

Comment: In which shell? What does `alias | grep ^g` output?

Comment: That code above would _work_ with ksh88, ksh93, pdksh, mksh, ash, dash, zsh, csh, tcsh... but not bash.

Comment: bash (tag added above).

Comment: I would advise you not to use aliases for these trivial tasks, because 1) you need to remember them all, and need aliases to refresh them and 2) when you're on another system, you're constantly typing not found aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of alias is lines starting with `alias`. So your alias should be:

```
alias ggg='alias | grep "^alias g"'
```

Comment: True for bash, not for ksh or zsh.

Comment: Didn't know that as I use bash, thanks for the addition!

Answer (score 4):

In zsh,

```
alias ggg='alias -m "g*"'
```

Or use a function, so that `ggg` doesn't print itself:

```
ggg() alias -m 'g*'
```

You could also grep the output of "alias", but it may not work properly if there are some multi-line aliases.

With bash, you could use this trick:

```
(
   alias() { [[ $1 = g* ]] && builtin alias "${1%%=*}"; }
   eval "$(builtin alias)"
)
```

The idea being that bash's `alias` outputs some text that is ready to be interpreted to reproduce the same aliases, something like:

```
$ alias
alias a='foo'
alias goo='gar
baz
alias gro=grar'
```

So we do evaluate it, but after having redefined `alias` as a function that calls the real `alias` only when passed a string that starts with "g".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your shell, if you are using bash @Dennis is completely right, for `zsh` it may be another issue if you enabled `EXTENDED_GLOB` in which case the `^` is interpreted by the shell and you have to quote it, i.e:

```
alias ggg='alias | grep "^g"'
```